# Android URI not matching

Tags: android

This is the most mind boggling errors I ever have in my entire life programming. In fact this is my worst so far. Can't believe I have been spending 4 days and I still come up with nothing. I certainly missed something.

Here is the AUTHORITY and CONTENT_URI variables from my code:

```
    public static final String AUTHORITY = "com.neonwarge.android.note.providers";
public static final Uri CONTENT_URI  = Uri.parse("content://" + AUTHORITY + "/" + NoteDatabaseHelper.NoteEntry.TABLE_NAME);
```

I've read a lot of post, they are all specific to their problems not very general and very unhelpful in my case.

So here is my code for URIs:

```
    static
{       
    mUriMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY , NoteDatabaseHelper.NoteEntry.TABLE_NAME, NOTES);

    // This never gets detected
    mUriMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY , NoteDatabaseHelper.NoteEntry.TABLE_NAME + "/#", NOTES_ID);
    //

    mUriMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY , NoteDatabaseHelper.NoteEntry.TABLE_NAME + "/#/", ALL_NOTES_BY_YEAR);
    mUriMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY , NoteDatabaseHelper.NoteEntry.TABLE_NAME + "/#/*", ALL_NOTES_BY_YEAR_MONTH);
    mUriMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY , NoteDatabaseHelper.NoteEntry.TABLE_NAME + "/#/*/#", ALL_NOTES_BY_YEAR_MONTH_DAY);

    mUriMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY , NoteDatabaseHelper.NoteEntry.TABLE_NAME + "/count/" , NOTE_COUNT);
    mUriMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY , NoteDatabaseHelper.NoteEntry.TABLE_NAME + "/count/#/", NOTE_COUNT_BY_YEAR);
    mUriMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY , NoteDatabaseHelper.NoteEntry.TABLE_NAME + "/count/#/*/", NOTE_COUNT_BY_YEAR_MONTH);
    mUriMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY , NoteDatabaseHelper.NoteEntry.TABLE_NAME + "/count/#/*/#", NOTE_COUNT_BY_YEAR_MONTH_DAY);

    mUriMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY , NoteDatabaseHelper.NoteEntry.TABLE_NAME + "/position/#", NOTE_POSITION);
    mUriMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY , NoteDatabaseHelper.NoteEntry.TABLE_NAME + "/percount/", NOTE_PERCOUNT_BY_ALL_YEARS);
    mUriMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY , NoteDatabaseHelper.NoteEntry.TABLE_NAME + "/percount/#/", NOTE_PERCOUNT_BY_ALL_MONTHS);
    mUriMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY , NoteDatabaseHelper.NoteEntry.TABLE_NAME + "/percount/#/*/", NOTE_PERCOUNT_BY_ALL_DAYS);
}
```

When I invoke contentResolver delete it never detects the pattern NOTES_ID. So I was very confused as to whether my content-uri matching is completely wrong. The concept here is that if my path is

```
content://com.sample.prog/mydatabase/1
```

This would mean I need to remove entry with ID = 1 from 'dmydatabasetabase'. This is not the case for NOTES_ID instead, the URI Matcher returns -1 that is why on my code it never touches the NOTES_ID case.

Here is how I called it:

```
    Uri uri = NoteProvider.CONTENT_URI.buildUpon().appendPath(String.valueOf(noteID)).build();
```

Any help in showing me where I committed mistake will be greatly appreciated. I have been trying to figure out this for four days!Very frustrating though.

Thanks!

Comment: you tried to debug match() method,  didn't you?  what was the result?

Comment: I did and its -1, I am sending content uri of this form: content://com.sample.prog/mydatabase/1 Still my UriMatcher cannot see this.

Comment: Thanks I re run my debugger again and this time I carefully looked at all instance of URI down to the call from the ContentResolver. It seems it is returning different value since I have URI leading to both /# and /#/ this causes ambiguity. I solve this by adding id/ path to the URI. But solving this didn't fix the problem either. It returns a path with %2EF and it seems back-slash is not encoded so I use .appendEncodedPath() instead. Thanks for the help!

Comment: when debugging,  did you step-in into match() method?

Comment: I did but I missed some URI down the lane and I was looking at the URI at the wrong function call! Which has the correct value. I was able to fix this now. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help and suggestion @pksink.

So I have the debugger run again twice as much this time and carefully retrieve all the URI down to the call to the ContentResolver. The culprit is this:

```
mUriMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY , NoteDatabaseHelper.NoteEntry.TABLE_NAME + "/#", NOTES_ID);
mUriMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY , NoteDatabaseHelper.NoteEntry.TABLE_NAME + "/#/", ALL_NOTES_BY_YEAR);
```

As you can see I have both paths to /# and /#/ and this causes ambiguity and in return, the matcher returns the type of the latter which my switch case didn't filter. Now I solve this by adding /id path. It didn't solve the problem as well either. The appended path looked like this all the time :

```
<blah><blah><mypath>%2EFid
```

I notice the back-slash isn't encoded so on my requesting URI string, I change the .appendPath to appendEncodedPath and this solves all of my URI problems!

Here is what the codes look like now:

```
    Uri uri = NoteProvider.CONTENT_URI.buildUpon().appendEncodedPath("id/" + String.valueOf(noteID)).build();
    int affectedRows = mContentResolver.delete(uri, selection, selectionArgs);
```